# rsync fails with Invalid argument (22)

Tags: rsync

I am trying to rsync my Evolution folder to an external disk, which is a NTFS — Mounted at /run/media/myself/TOSHIBA EXT. I am on a Fedora 32 machine.

When I run

```
sudo rsync -r  -t  -v --progress  -u -s /home/myself/.local/share/evolution/ \
/run/media/myself/'TOSHIBA EXT'/backUpDesktopDic2021/local/share/evolution
```

I get errors like (`mainmail` being a Evolution folder)

```
rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/run/media/myself/TOSHIBA EXT/backUpDesktopDic2021/local/share/evolution/mail/local/..AAAA_5FInbox_5Fmainmail.inbox_5Fmainmail_5F2015/cur/.1420204086.18521_3492.localhost.localdomain:2,S.cQifAt" failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

If I try with options `--temp-dir=/tmp --no-owner --no-group`, I get errors like

```
rsync: [receiver] open "/run/media/myself/TOSHIBA EXT/backUpDesktopDic2021/local/share/evolution/mail/local/..AAAA_5FInbox_5Fmainmail.myfriend/cur/1539545866.7691_15362.fedora-pc:2,": Invalid argument (22)
rsync: [receiver] copy "/tmp/1539545866.7691_15362.fedora-pc:2,.GY2eMO" -> "mail/local/..AAAA_5FInbox_5Fmainmail.myfriend/cur/1539545866.7691_15362.fedora-pc:2,": Invalid argument (22)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114461/make-linux-forbid-colons-in-file-names-on-ntfs-partitions  and this more general search: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=colon+ntfs

Comment: @roaima Yes, it could be an issue with  characters that are not allowed on the target disk. Since I do not want to encode them, I am looking at the option to tarball my source folder.

Comment: comment by @roaima has been erased?

Comment: Comments can be erased at any time. Mine will have been deleted automatically when you accepted that you're question was a duplicate of the one I suggested. Regards.

Comment: I see, thanks, take care